# GStreamer pipeline doesn't proceed with `pipelinesrc`

Tags: gstreamer, pipewire

I am attempting to capture my desktop using pipewire and gstreamer. I am using the following command

`gst-launch-1.0 -vvv pipewiresrc path=$PATH ! videoconvert ! tee name=split ! queue ! fakesink split. ! x264enc speed-preset=superfast tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true sliced-threads=true threads=12 ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au,width=1920,height=1080 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=$PORT`

However, it freezes when the timestamp appears and never outputs anything.

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstPipeWireSrc:pipewiresrc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)Y444
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTee:split.GstTeePad:src_0: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)Y444
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)Y444
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTee:split.GstTeePad:src_1: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)Y444
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)Y444
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)Y444
Redistribute latency...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstX264Enc:x264enc0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)Y444
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTee:split.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)Y444
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: pipewireclock0
Redistribute latency...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstX264Enc:x264enc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.2, profile=(string)high-4:4:4, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.2, profile=(string)high-4:4:4, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.2, profile=(string)high-4:4:4, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.2, profile=(string)high-4:4:4, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, ssrc=(uint)133320936, timestamp-offset=(uint)789806277, seqnum-offset=(uint)15098, a-framerate=(string)60
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, ssrc=(uint)133320936, timestamp-offset=(uint)789806277, seqnum-offset=(uint)15098, a-framerate=(string)60
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, packetization-mode=(string)1, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"Z/QAKpGWgHgCJ+JwFqAgICgAAAMACAAAAwPEeMGV\,aO8xkhk\=", payload=(int)96, seqnum-offset=(uint)15098, timestamp-offset=(uint)789806277, ssrc=(uint)133320936, a-framerate=(string)60
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, packetization-mode=(string)1, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"Z/QAKpGWgHgCJ+JwFqAgICgAAAMACAAAAwPEeMGV\,aO8xkhk\=", payload=(int)96, seqnum-offset=(uint)15098, timestamp-offset=(uint)789806277, ssrc=(uint)133320936, a-framerate=(string)60
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: timestamp = 789806277
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: seqnum = 15098
Redistribute latency...
0:00:00.0 / 99:99:99.
```

However, using `autovideosink` in place of `fakesink` makes it work peachily (Is that a word?)

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstPipeWireSrc:pipewiresrc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)YV12
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTee:split.GstTeePad:src_0: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)YV12
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)YV12
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTee:split.GstTeePad:src_1: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)YV12
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)YV12
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad0: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)YV12
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)YV12
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)YV12
Redistribute latency...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstX264Enc:x264enc0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)YV12
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTee:split.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, format=(string)YV12
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: pipewireclock0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstX264Enc:x264enc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.2, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.2, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.2, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.2, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)0/1, max-framerate=(fraction)60/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, ssrc=(uint)758478195, timestamp-offset=(uint)4089353331, seqnum-offset=(uint)7752, a-framerate=(string)60
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, ssrc=(uint)758478195, timestamp-offset=(uint)4089353331, seqnum-offset=(uint)7752, a-framerate=(string)60
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, packetization-mode=(string)1, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"Z2QAKqy0A8ARPy4C1AQEBQAAAwABAAADAHiPGDKg\,aO88sA\=\=", payload=(int)96, seqnum-offset=(uint)7752, timestamp-offset=(uint)4089353331, ssrc=(uint)758478195, a-framerate=(string)60
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, packetization-mode=(string)1, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"Z2QAKqy0A8ARPy4C1AQEBQAAAwABAAADAHiPGDKg\,aO88sA\=\=", payload=(int)96, seqnum-offset=(uint)7752, timestamp-offset=(uint)4089353331, ssrc=(uint)758478195, a-framerate=(string)60
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: timestamp = 4089353331
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: seqnum = 7752
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:15.160166600
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening, and how to fix it? I'm running GStreamer version 1.20.0 and kernel version 5.18.6-200 on Fedora. I've encountered this issue before with just a straight pipeline (without the tee into another sink), but without it the stream doesn't proceed after the first timestamp is posted, much like if `fakesink` is put in instead of `autovideosink`, which makes me think it may be an issue with `pipelinesrc`. The stream works with `videotestsrc`